# Combine publisher for changes to UIStackView's arrangedSubviews array

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, combine

I have a basic view controller subclass which contains a UIStackView and a UIButton. I want to run some code each time a view is added or removed from the stack view's `arrangedSubviews` array using Combine. Here's is my failed attempt to do this:

```swift
import Combine
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    var cancelables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stackView.publisher(for: \.arrangedSubviews).sink { views in
            button.isEnabled = views.count < 5
        }
        .store(in: &cancelables)
    }

    @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let customView = CustomView()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(customView)
    }
}
```

Each time I tap the button, a new view is added to the stack view, but the change to `arrangedSubviews` is not published, which doesn't trigger the code in the `sink` block. In the case above, the button is still enabled even if `arrangedSubviews.count` is more than 5.

How can I fix this so that I can correctly publish changes whenever a new view is added or removed from the `arrangedSubviews` array?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Isn't this basically just the standard problem of observing changes to the contents of an array?

Comment: @matt This is what I'm assuming, but I'm not sure. the contents of the array in this case are `UIView`'s which are reference types. I'm not sure if this is what's causing this not to work. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK `publisher(for:` works only on KVO-compliant properties and I don't think that's the case for `UIStackView.arrangedSubviews`.

Comment: @FabioFelici Thank you for this info. I didn't know about it before. Is there any other way to react to insertions and removals to `UIStackView.arrangedSubviews`? Even without Combine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Fabio Felici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4105619/fabio-felici)'s comment, I guess `UIStackView.arrangedSubviews` is not KVO-compliant, which must be what's causing my attempt to not work.

I managed to handle this a different way, by subclassing `UIStackView` and adding a `Published` counter which contains the updated value of `arrangedSubviews.count` each time insertion and removal functions are called.

```swift
class CountReactableStackView: UIStackView {
    @Published var numberOfArrangedSubviews = 0
    
    override func addArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        super.addArrangedSubview(view)
        numberOfArrangedSubviews = arrangedSubviews.count
    }
    
    override func removeArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        super.removeArrangedSubview(view)
        numberOfArrangedSubviews = arrangedSubviews.count
    }
    
    override func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, at stackIndex: Int) {
        super.insertArrangedSubview(view, at: stackIndex)
        numberOfArrangedSubviews = arrangedSubviews.count
    }
}
```

I then subscribe and react to `numberOfArrangedSubviews`.

Since `arrangedSubviews` is read-only and can be only changed by the functions above, this simple solution answers my question. I'm still curious if there's a way to observe and react to insertions and deletions to `arrangedSubviews` directly.